# Visual Studio 2017 don't remember option "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

VS don't remember this option is check, when restart the IDE or change project branch.

I always check this option when I open the IDE.

I am using VS 17 Enterprise latest version.

**EDIT:** I am also using resharper(maybe it override VS options).

Comment: I can't understand why this question is downvoted? Keep comment why did you downvote to improve question qulity. If it is not clear you can ask/advise or any comment.

Comment: I check that box since it has existed and never had this type of problem. Have you tried to remove R#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I change resharper performance options, than it doesn't work. Following option affect VS option:

[image]

If you select `fix silently` then it is overriding the VS settings.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of known issues with "Track Active Item":

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search.html?f=&type=question+OR+problem+OR+idea&type=question+OR+problem+OR+idea&c=&redirect=search%2Fsearch&sort=relevance&q=Track+Active+Item

A summary of most of the issues is already provided by @Davemundo

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (ensure you are on the LATEST VS2017):

- As per comments: "I've found that it works reliably when Solution Explorer is in Solution mode. But when working in Folder mode, the behaviour is temperamental."
- Toggle lightweight loading on/off (https://dotnetvibes.com/2017/02/13/lightweight-solution-load-in-visual-studio-2017/)
- Disable the extensions in VS one-at-a-time to determine which one, if any, cause this
- Completely uninstall Productivity Power Toys (PPT) (disable wont work)
- Remove the .vs folder (as per other suggestions)

This has to be reproducible, others have had similar problems with different versions, please let us know which version number you are using right now, thanks!